# Jquery .load - multiple ids with different data at once - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to modify a Wordpress plugin so that it would execute admin-ajax.php script less frequently. The plugin displays polls on pages - it loads them asynchronously after the document is ready. Script in question is the below written async-load.js. Now the .load is used within a for loop to display each poll on a page (each page has multiple polls). This executes the admin-ajax script for every poll on the page - for example if there is 10 polls the script gets executed 10 times.

I'm wondering if the script can be modified so that it would display all polls only with one admin-ajax.php script execution.

Here is the full code:

```
if (window['tp_async_polls']) {
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var pollContainer = [];
    var pollID = []; 

    $(tp_async_polls).each(function (index, poll) {
        //tp_async_polls gives an array of object with keys id and container  
        pollContainer.push(poll.container);

        //store each poll's container id in array

        pollID.push(poll.id);

        //store each poll's id in array 
    });

 for (i=1; i < pollContainer.length; i++) {

     //loop through polls and display them - here the admin-ajax.php gets executed for every poll that is on a page. Looking for solution to only execute it once per page load. 
        $(pollContainer[i]).load(totalpoll_cache_compatibility.ajaxurl, {action: 'load_tp', tp_poll_id: pollID[i]}, function () {

            FastClick.attach(this);
            $(this).animateVotesBar();
        });
    };
});
```

};

Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is only the general idea of what you should do, it's **NOT** a working sample.

In your example, the variable `pollID` is an `Array`, containing the ids of all the polls.

Instead of loop through all the of the containers and request the content of each of them, you can send 1 request with the list of the ids (`pollID`), and once the data is received - you can updated the polls accordingly.

Let request's data should changed from

```
{action: 'load_tp', tp_poll_id: pollID[i]}
```

to something like

```
{action: 'load_tps', all_poll_ids: pollID}
```

The code in your server should return something like this:

```
{
    165 : '<div> CONTENT OF HTML FOR POLL ID = 165</div>',
    179 : '<div> CONTENT OF HTML FOR POLL ID = 179</div>',
    ....
}
```

And you can sent the request using `$.ajax` that looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: totalpoll_cache_compatibility.ajaxurl,
    data: {action: 'load_tps', all_poll_ids: pollID},
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(poll_id, poll_html) {
            $(pollContainer[poll_id]).html(poll_html)
            ...
        });
    }
    ...
});
```